# How do I add a custom field on a single page

Tags: wordpress

I need to add a field (text editor) on a Wordpress page, but it's just on a page, whatever specific page by id or slug.

Note: it is a custom field in the WordPress dashboard. It should appear when I edit this page specifies. No plugin, only via code because I do not see the need to install a plugin to do that.

How do I do that?

Thank you in advance! Hail for all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi add this code in your functions.php file

look like bellow image.
[image]

```
/* Define the custom box */
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'myplugin_add_custom_box' );

/* Do something with the data entered */
add_action( 'save_post', 'myplugin_save_postdata' );

/* Adds a box to the main column on the Post and Page edit screens */
function myplugin_add_custom_box() {
  add_meta_box( 'wp_editor_test_1_box', 'WP Editor Test #1 Box', 'wp_editor_meta_box', 'post' );
}

/* Prints the box content */
function wp_editor_meta_box( $post ) {


  // Use nonce for verification
  wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'myplugin_noncename' );

  $field_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_editor_test_1', false );

  // Settings that we'll pass to wp_editor
  $args = array (
        'tinymce' => false,
        'quicktags' => true,
  );
  wp_editor( $field_value[0], '_wp_editor_test_1', $args );
}

/* When the post is saved, saves our custom data */
function myplugin_save_postdata( $post_id ) {

  // verify if this is an auto save routine. 
  // If it is our form has not been submitted, so we dont want to do anything
  if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
      return;

  // verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
  // because save_post can be triggered at other times
  if ( ( isset ( $_POST['myplugin_noncename'] ) ) && ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['myplugin_noncename'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) )
      return;

  // Check permissions
  if ( ( isset ( $_POST['post_type'] ) ) && ( 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] )  ) {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
      return;
    }    
  }
  else {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
      return;
    }
  }

  // OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data
  if ( isset ( $_POST['_wp_editor_test_1'] ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_wp_editor_test_1', $_POST['_wp_editor_test_1'] );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the advanced Custom fields (ACF ) plugin ( Free ) available in WordPress repository and then you can select a field group in it and then all the fields that you want.

For a text editor you may use WSYWIG editor as the field type and once you are done selecting your fields you can select the location as the page or post where you want this to show.

Advanced Custom Fields is according to me one of the top 5 plugins for WP that there are so take time out and learn it and you can use this in a variety of ways.

Hope this helps

Take care and happy coding

Comment: sorry, i need without plugin. only one field the place for all , not I see the need to hum plugin for it.

Comment: sorry I never did that without this plugin as most other authors